# How to rename only 'Unnamed:' columns as numeric index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I am reading excel file as a `data frame`. However, first three of my columns have headers and the rest need just an **numeric index**. When I read the file in I get output below.

```
        a         b         c    Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6
0  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209  0.109066   -1.112704   -0.545209
1  0.447114  1.525341  0.317252  0.109066   -1.112704   -0.545209
2  0.507495  0.137863  0.886283  1.452867    1.888363    1.168101
3  1.452867  1.888363  1.168101  0.901371   -0.704805    0.088335
4  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335  0.901371   -0.704805    0.088335
```

I would like to have data frame looking like this, keeping in mind that number of unnamed columns could vary.

```
        a         b         c        1           2           3
0  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209  0.109066   -1.112704   -0.545209
1  0.447114  1.525341  0.317252  0.109066   -1.112704   -0.545209
2  0.507495  0.137863  0.886283  1.452867    1.888363    1.168101
3  1.452867  1.888363  1.168101  0.901371   -0.704805    0.088335
4  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335  0.901371   -0.704805    0.088335
```

How could I rename all of the `Unnamed: #` columns and assign them numeric index?

Comment: Is the column called "unnamed" or does it have no name at all (i.e., blank)?

Comment: Pandas by default assigns it  `Unnamed: #`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you should hardcode your mappings. Use a list comprehension.

```
In [550]: i = iter(range(1, len(df.columns) + 1))

In [551]: df.columns = [x if not x.startswith('Unnamed') else next(i) for x in df.columns]

In [552]: df
Out[552]: 
          a         b         c         1         2         3
0  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209
1  0.447114  1.525341  0.317252  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209
2  0.507495  0.137863  0.886283  1.452867  1.888363  1.168101
3  1.452867  1.888363  1.168101  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335
4  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create `dict` and then `rename`:

```
a = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]
d = dict(zip(a, range(1, len(a)+1)))
print (d)
{'Unnamed: 4': 1, 'Unnamed: 6': 3, 'Unnamed: 5': 2}

df = df.rename(columns=d)
print (df)
          a         b         c         1         2         3
0  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209
1  0.447114  1.525341  0.317252  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209
2  0.507495  0.137863  0.886283  1.452867  1.888363  1.168101
3  1.452867  1.888363  1.168101  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335
4  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335
```